# Read file and search another file using awk

Tags: shell, file, awk

I am reading a file having numbers on each line.
I need to search another file meeting conditions on those numbers and other conditions. I am trying to do this using awk, but face a problem.

File `a.txt`:

```
1476
1477
1497
```

Now I need to print lines having these numbers at 12th column along with having 0 at 3rd column.

File `b.txt`:

```
r 1.040496 2 1 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1165
r 1.040496 2 1 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1165
r 1.050528 2 1 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1165
r 1.050528 1 0 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1165
r 1.050528 1 0 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1476
r 1.06056 1 0 ack 40 ------- 1 3.0 0.0 0 1165
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1203
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1203
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 2 1477
r 1.061392 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 2 1204
r 1.071392 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1497
r 1.071392 1 2 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1203
```

My script:

```
while read LINE
do
    awk -F ' ' '($3 == 0) && ($12 == $LINE)' b.txt
done < a.txt
```

Returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ while read line; do awk -v x="$line" '($3 == 0) && ($12 == x)' b.txt; done < a.txt
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 2 1477
r 1.071392 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1497
```

Here, we use the `-v` option to assign awk variable `x` to have the value of shell variable `$line`.

#### Simplification

We don't need the shell loop:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $3==0 && $12 in a' a.txt b.txt
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 2 1477
r 1.071392 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1497
```

While reading the first file, a.txt, we create a key is associative array `a` for the value on each line.

When reading the second file, b.txt, we print the line if `$3==0` and field 12, `$12`, is a key in associative array `a`.

#### Adding a column

> *"What if i need to add the 2nd column of the result?"*

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $3==0 && $12 in a {s+=$2; print} END{print "Sum=",s+0}' a.txt b.txt
r 1.06056 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 2 1477
r 1.071392 0 1 tcp 1040 ------- 1 0.0 3.0 1 1497
Sum= 2.13195
```

Comment: One more help. What if i need to add the 2nd column of the result?

Comment: Do you want to add all the second columns in b.txt or just the ones on the selected lines?

Comment: add second column of the printed result.

Comment: Works perfect!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code -

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next;} $3==0 && $NF in a {print $0}' a.txt b.txt
```