# Two-file processing in awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have file :

result.txt

```
Apple fruits 10 20 30
Car  vehicle 40 50 60
Book study  70 80 90
```

Assume here 2nd column is a feature, 3rd column is Min, 4th column is Median, 5th column is Max. I have another file `config.txt` which contains a property for each feature i.e.

config.txt

```
fruits Max
vehicle Median
study Min
```

So I want to write a script which shows only that column number for the feature which is defined in `config.txt` file.

Expected output:

```
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70
```

I am following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206489/10220825. Here what I have tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$2];next} $1 in arr {var =$2;print var}' result.txt config.txt
```

I am able to hold the property (like Min, Max, Median) in a variable for the corresponding feature defined in `result.txt`, but not able to display the column for that variable. Please suggest me an approach on how to print the column for the corresponding column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {m["Min"]=3; m["Median"]=4; m["Max"]=5} 
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
               {print $1,$2,$m[a[$2]]}' config result

Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70
```

you need to keep a map of min/median/max to the corresponding column index and lookup through the config file which value needs to be printed.

add `a[$2]` to the print if you want to print Max/Min/Median information.

`NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}` is the `awk` idiom to load file1 into an array indexed with first field and field two as values, essentially a dictionary or a lookup table.

Comment: One more help plz, how could I print the property along with the result. i.e `Apple fruits Max 30`

Comment: Also explain, what is the meanining of  `a[$1]=$2; next` on above code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl as well

```
perl -lane ' BEGIN { @kv{qw(Min Median Max)}=(2,3,4);
            %kw=map{chomp;split} qx(cat ratnesh_config.txt) } 
            $p=$kv{$kw{$F[1]}}; print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[$p]" ' ratnesh_in.txt
```

with the given inputs:

```
$ cat ratnesh_config.txt
fruits Max
vehicle Median
study Min

$ cat ratnesh_in.txt
Apple fruits 10 20 30
Car  vehicle 40 50 60
Book study  70 80 90

$ perl -lane 'BEGIN { @kv{qw(Min Median Max)}=(2,3,4);%kw=map{chomp;split} qx(cat ratnesh_config.txt) } $p=$kv{$kw{$F[1]}}; print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[$p]" ' ratnesh_in.txt

Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70

$ perl -lane 'BEGIN { $kv{Min}=2;$kv{Median}=3;$kv{Max}=4;%kw=map{chomp;split} qx(cat ratnesh_config.txt) } $p=$kv{$kw{$F[1]}}; print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[$p]" ' ratnesh_in
.txt
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70

$ perl -lane 'BEGIN { @kv{qw(Min Median Max)}=(2,3,4);%kw=map{chomp;split} qx(cat ratnesh_config.txt)} $p=$kv{$kw{$F[1]}}; print "@F[0,1,$p]" ' ratnesh_in.txt
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70

$
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2,"max"]=$1 OFS $5
  a[$2,"min"]=$1 OFS $3
  a[$2,"median"]=$1 OFS $4
  next
}
{
  $2=tolower($2)
}
(($1,$2) in a){
  split(a[$1,$2],array," ")
  print array[1],$1,array[2]
}' SUBSEP=" "  results.txt config.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Apple fruits 30
Car vehicle 50
Book study 70
```