# Printing content in two file processing in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am referring this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54767231/11084572.
I have a `config file` where `2nd column is feature` and `3rd column is action`. I have another large file where I need to match the 1st column of this file to the 1st column of the `config file` and perform action according to the feature.

Assumption: In File.txt column are named as `Min (3rd col),Median (4th), Max(5th)`

Config.txt

```
Apple  All  Max
Car    abc  Median
Car    xyz  Min
Book   cvb  Median
Book   pqr  Max
```

File.txt

```
Apple  first   10  20  30
Apple  second  20  30  40
Car    abc     10  20  30
Car    xyz     20  30  40
Car    wxyz    10  20  30
Book   cvb     60  70  80
Book   pqr     80  90  100
```

Expected Output:

```
Apple  first   30
Apple  second  40
Car    abc     20
Car    xyz     20
Car    wxyz    10
Book   cvb     70
Book   pqr     100
```

The above output is generated on the followinfg approach:

1) Since the `file.txt` is large, so if the feature (2nd col) of `config file` is ALL, so all the matching 1st column would perform action according to the 3rd col of `config file`.

2) Otherwise it perform if the 2nd col of `config file` matches as `**substring**` to the 2nd col of `file.txt`

Here what I have tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {m["Min"]=3;m["Median"]=4;m["Max"]=5}

        NR==FNR{ arr[$1]=$2;brr[$1]=$3;next}
                ($1 in arr && arr[$1]=="All") {print $1,$2,$m[brr[$1]]}
                ($1 in arr && $2==arr[$1] ) {print $1 ,$2,$m[brr[$1]]}
' Config.txt File.txt
```

Code output:

```
Apple  first   30
Apple  second  40
Book   pqr     100
Car    xyz     20
```

The above output is only printing one field of matched 1st col (like `Book cvb 70` is not printing). Also how could I matched the string as ending string (Ex. `xyz` defined in config.txt matches to both `xyz and wxyz` of file.txt .

Please help me to solve above challenge. Thanks!

Comment: in your `Assumption:` maybe you meant `File.txt` instead `Config.txt` (?)

Comment: @downtheroad    Yes, in File.txt

Comment: @RATNESHTIWARI, please be careful in posting samples seems line `Car    abc     200` not matching your first Input_file, if that is the case then kindly update your samples.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected sample output is NOT looking as per your shown sample of Input_file(eg--> `Car    abc     200` where there is NO `200` in `file.txt`), if I got it correctly could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  b["min"]=3
  b["max"]=5
  b["median"]=4
}
FNR==NR{
  c[$1]
  ++d[$1]
  a[$1 d[$1]]=tolower($NF)
  next
}
($1 in c){
  if(e[$1]<d[$1]){
      ++e[$1]
  }
  else{
      e[$1]!=""?e[$1]:++e[$1]
  }
  print $1,$2,$b[a[$1 e[$1]]]
}' config.txt file.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Apple first 30
Apple second 40
Car abc 20
Car xyz 20
Car wxyz 10
Book cvb 70
Book pqr 100
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                                      ##Mentioning BEGIN section here which will be executed once and before reading Input_file only.
  b["min"]=3                                ##Creating an array named b whose index is string min and value is 3.
  b["max"]=5                                ##Creating an array named b whose index is string max and value is 5.
  b["median"]=4                             ##Creating an array named b whose index is string median and value is 4.
}                                           ##Closing BLOCK section here.
FNR==NR{                                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be executed when 1st Input_file named config.txt is being read.
  c[$1]                                     ##Creating an array named c whose index is $1.
  ++d[$1]                                   ##Creating an array named d and with index is $1 whose value is keep increasing with 1 on its each occurence.
  a[$1 d[$1]]=tolower($NF)                  ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value of d[$1] and value is small letters value of $NF(last column) of current line.
  next                                      ##Using next keyword of awk to skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in c){                                  ##Checking conditions if $1 of current line is present of array c then do following.
  if(e[$1]<d[$1]){                          ##Checking condition if value of e[$1] is lesser than d[$1] then do following.
      ++e[$1]                               ##Creating array named e whose index is $1 and incrementing its value with 1 here.
  }
  else{                                     ##Using else for above if condition here.
      e[$1]!=""?e[$1]:++e[$1]               ##Checking if e[$1] is NULL then increment it with 1 or leave it as it is.
  }
  print $1,$2,$b[a[$1 e[$1]]]               ##Printing 1st, 2nd fields value along with field value of array b whose index is value of array a with index of $1 e[$1] here.
}' config.txt file.txt                      ##Mentioning Input_files here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!! Can you please explain the code in brief. What is the need of `tolower` in here. Please explain your approach!!

Comment: @RATNESHTIWARI, yes explanation is on its way. BTW `tolower` I am using to make strings into small letters form. So that no confusions either your file has like `MAX OR `Max` OR `max` etc. Since it is changing them in small letters so I need NOT to hard-code these values to be matched.

Comment: @RATNESHTIWARI, added complete explanation now, kindly check it once.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation. But explanation needs the purpose of using the above variable/array and its impact on output.

Comment: @RATNESHTIWARI, purpose is to match OP's/yours expected output, if you read explanation more clearly you may get its pulse, let me know your confusions and could try to solve them then.

Comment: if(e[$1]<d[$1]){                         
      ++e[$1]                               
  }